# C# get Call information from VOIP

Tags: c#, call, voip

I want to be notified and get caller info (the phone number and line number from VOIP) when someone calls and also get the status of call (Answer, End, Rejected). We have a VOIP server that has an IP address and also we have username and password for connecting to VOIP server.
How should I implement this functionality?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Using dialog subscription might be one of the options (and this would use only SIP), but it depends on server support, information set passed in dialog notifications may vary. I'm also not sure if it would be possible to distinguish between call rejected and call canceled.